# How to find the line in code, which causes an error? VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a trouble with my code. I get two error:

> Error C2296   '<': illegal, left operand has type 'const _Ty'

> Error C2297   '<': illegal, right operand has type 'const _Ty'

But compiler tells me, that I should look at `127 line of xstddef header`.
How to determine which exact line in my code uses this illegal symbol? My code is too long, I cannot do it manually. I tried search panel in Visual Studio, however it seemed to be useless.

Comment: Copy the exact, complete error message(s) from the Output Window (not the Error List window), starting with the *first* one.

Comment: error list is only a compilation of results, it lacks required information in most  cases save most trivial ones. You have to look in output window for actual report on the problem. Some declarations, ill-formed use of templates or macroses may generate long chains of problems as the compiler doesn't know programmer's intent.